# Elasticseach array in array

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I want to store following data in ElasticSearch.
Can someone let me know how to store array of array :

```
{
  "cars": [
    [
      {
        "car": "merc",
        "color": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "car": "merc",
        "color": "red"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "car": "bmw",
        "color": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "car": "bmw",
        "color": "red"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you add how you want to query the data? That's where nested comes into play

Comment: For now there is no requirement of querying nested data. Each object in Elastic search has an id and I query based only on id

Comment: Then you can just store the documents the way you have them right now. But don't forget: If you want to query for elements in a specific subdocument, you will need to have a nested mapping and you would have to reindex your existing documents to get that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably cannot store arrays of arrays, query for the pair. [reference](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/what-is-the-mapping-for-array-of-arrays/64039/2).

> you cannot really store arrays of arrays directly and then query for a
>   specific pair, due to the way this data is stored internally in
>   Lucene. The documentation about [Array datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) and [Nested datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)
>   explain this in more detail and also provide an alternative, depending
>   on how you need to access your data later.

Comment: Actually, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/properties.html  says that "datatype" can be "nested" too. I was wondering if thats possible. Could not find any guide or samples for that

Comment: @user3527619, but the nested type has been all flatten. Then "query for inner structure" lost the meaning, right?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this data. i am able to enter this data from kibana.

```
POST /cars/information/1
{
  "cars": [
    [
      {
        "car": "merc",
        "color": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "car": "merc",
        "color": "red"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        "car": "bmw",
        "color": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "car": "bmw",
        "color": "red"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Here 'cars' is index, 'information' is type and '1' is id. Try it from kibana and then search query by this request

```
GET /cars/information/_search
```